# Derive the virial theorem from hydrostatic equikibrium

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, stellar-physics, virial-theorem

Consider the equation of hydrostatic equilibirium as follows as applied to a stellar object:
$$ \frac{dP}{dr }   = \frac{-GM\rho}{r^2}  $$

I know it is intimately related to the virial theorem but I am unsure how to derive the virial theorem from the above expression. I tried integrating as follows: $$\int_0 ^P dP  = \int_0 ^R \frac{-Gm\rho}{r^2} dr$$

However I run into a problem as infinity gets in to the expression.

Ay help would be appreciated.

Someone asked for a source:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use 0 as the lower limit since you are using a point mass for your force.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your first equation, please?

Comment: I just uploaded the text from where I obtained it

Comment: Read on virial theorem here, https://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~nefs/BasicStellarPhysics.pdf , sec. 2.2